# cross platform input Unity with custom controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile-controls

I'm new to unity but i have made a custom character controller and I am trying to use unity 5's standard assets cross platform input to make my game compatible with android and iOS (using joysticks for movement).

The **Standard assets first Person character controller** works with the joysticks but i don't know how (and cannot find out how) to make the joysticks work with **my** FPController

Comment: Can you paste some code on how you are reading the input? There are several ways of doing it. Without that, I could only recommend you look at: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you dropped UI/EventSystem in your scene (and mark allow activation on mobile device)
2. drop MobileSingleStickControl in your scene

check up this video : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7YiASYgDC0&feature=youtu.be&t=5m30s
(in unity 4.5)

good luck